# Rewrite all requests through a directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My site `www.example.com` has its document root to `public_html` directory. But, all of my content is hosted in `public_html/www.example.com/`. So, I want when a user visits my site he get contents from `public_html/www.example.com/` and not `public_html`. So, what should be the .htaccess rewrite rule for that?

I am not good in rewrite rules but the best I found was:

```
RewriteRule !^blog blog%{REQUEST_URI}
```

There are two problems with this.

- It will not work properly if user requested `www.example.com/blog/`
- It will also not work when we use directory name as `www.example.com`

Comment: Why are you putting everything in `www.example.com` in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and let me know if it works for you, and if it doesn't try to describe as detailed as possible what happens.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. Actually I am using this to prevent my cPanel account from getting mess.